# Data storage on ubuntu AWS

Tags: 12.04, storage, aws

My client needs 500 GB data space on cloud (AWS). I had created a ubuntu 12.04 and wonder how do I give my client access to my ubuntu share on AWS? How will my client access it and can they map it as a drive or will be using any client side software to access it (apart from ftp)? or what is the professional way to make this share on server and to give my client access.

Also they might access from ipads and iphones. Any solution please.

PS: my clients will be using windows platform.

Comment: What will happen when two or more users/clients are opening and changing the same file concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup up the share as an SSHFS type filesystem then use win-sshfs to mount the share on the Windows Client.

https://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/

This would provide a very secure File Sytem share across the internet to your AWS Ubuntu Server.

Comment: cant't we map a drive in windows for the standard shares in ubuntu (on AWS) and access it via its public IP?

Answer (score 0):

Use AWS simple storage service (S3).
You can find many tools and software for working or mapping S3 bucket for sharing files.
You choose Hardway for cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

Create S3 Butkcet would be the best option in AWS also by creating IAM user and assign permission for that bucket and suggest to use S3 browser [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwieqPKW8PfNAhUPR48KHfGGD4AQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fs3browser.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNF9GexLavEL1U-Bc3pBxPaKUz1qLw&sig2=2Lwi7XddzFPvb5jCefdu3A&bvm=bv.127178174,d.c2I):

Also user can access the S3 bucket through AWS Console using their IAM created for User.

If you have attached storage (EBS) with your server then you share it by Creating key based access would be batter way

If it's limited then use separate ftp account for your client.